# .htaccess hide question mark from address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What am I doing wrong?
I have a link :

`<a href="norma/something1/something2/something3/">Link Name</a>`

I am need to make an address from:
`eshop.mydomain.com/norma/something1/something2/something3/`

this adress:
`eshop.mydomain.com/norma-something1-something2-something3.html`

the only thing I can do is
`eshop.mydomain.com/?norma-something1-something2-something3.html`

I need to hide the question mark, but I do not have any idea how :(

Here is my .htaccess

```
#php_value memory_limit 256M 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /index.php / [R=301]

RewriteRule ^norma/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([\d\.]+)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?$1-$2&-$3.html [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /doc/e404/
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding that question mark in your rewrite rule:

```
# right here -----------------------------------------------------------v
RewriteRule ^norma/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([\d\.]+)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?$1-$2&-$3.html [L,QSA]
```

But I suspect it may be a couple of things that's causing this redirect to happen when it really should be a rewrite internally on the server side. Try changing your rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# this L is important ------------v
RewriteRule ^/?index.php / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^norma/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([\d\.]+)$ /index.php?$1-$2&-$3.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: if I use this, my page throws error<br/>

`Moved Permanently<br/>

The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Here is code:<br><br>

`#php_value memory_limit 256M 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/index.php / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^norma/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([\d\.]+)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?$1-$2-$3.html&pa=norma&stupen=$1&cislo=$2&datum=$3 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /doc/e404/`

Comment: @LeníkRostík What does the link go to when the error document says `The document has moved here.`?

Comment: The document has moved <a href="http://eshop.mydomain.com/norma/something1/something2/something3">here.

Comment: Where can be problem please ?

Comment: @LeníkRostík I don't know, you could try removing the `RewriteRule ^/?index.php / [R=301,L]` line entirely, not sure what you're trying to do with that. You could also remove the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` from the last rule like I have in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I am rewrite this: ------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^/?index.php / [R=301,L]
----------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^norma/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([\d\.]+)$ /index.php?norma-$1-$2-$3.html [L,QSA]----------------------------------------------
Bug i see link "http://eshop.mydomain.com/?norma-something1-something2-something3.html" But I am need delete "?" from adress.

Comment: @LeníkRostík If the actual page you are trying to go to is literally `http://eshop.mydomain.com/norma/something1/something2/something3`, it's not going to work because your regular expression matchings only numbers at the end (where "something3" is).

Comment: And if I have link <a href="/norma/something1/something2/something3">LINK</a> i have problem  convert to norma-something1-something2-something.html ? I am really need delete "?" from adress, becouse now i have "eshop.mydomain.com/?norma-something1-something2-something3.html". Is there a chance that somehow remove the question mark?